# Move row of data to different sheet based on dropdown value in specified column

Tags: excel, vba

Summary: I am trying to create a automated excel spreadsheet that uses a VBA code to move rows of data from one sheet to another based on the value people select in a validated drop down list in one of my columns.

Detail: I am creating a task tracking spreadsheet that allows my team and I to track the progress of projects we are individually working on. I have data validated the columns based on my needs and conditionally formatted the cells to change color. That stuff I am fine with.

I am hoping someone here can help me with a VBA macro code to automatically move any row where we change the completion status to [COMPLETED] on the [Team Tasks] (Image 1) to the other worksheet named [Completed Tasks] (Image 2) when we save and exit the document whilst simultaneously removing it from the [Team Tasks] worksheet. I don't need any formatting to go across with the row, just the data.

I hope I have provided enough information. I have watched a number of online videos and looked at a number of posts but I just can't seem to get it to work for me. It's a bit beyond my basic skills with VBA.

Thanks

[Team Tasks Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSpd7.png)
[Completed Tasks Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu0AO.png)

Comment: 1. Did you try something on your own? 2. The pictures are completely irrelevant against the question as you expressed. You should show us how **a row to be copied looks in the second sheet**. In this second one (if 'this second one' means the bottom of your single picture) are not any of the first one fields, except "COMPLETED" which does not mean anything...

Comment: Could you add some examples of your code and your work pls. For more clearance, thank you.

Comment: 1. I tried a few different methods after watching YouTube how to tutorials but there wasn't anything specific that I found. 2. The 2nd image shows how I want the data to look once it is transferred over. Image 1 shows the different ways data could be input into the worksheet. Image 2 shows only the [completed] row coming across into the 2nd sheet. I will give it another attempt myself and post the code soon.